# Unlock device when activity appears on Android

Tags: android, wakelock, android-wake-lock

I have an app which should unlock the screen when it appears.

I have tried something, wrote some code both in .java file and AndroidManifest, but it is not able to unlock device.

Here is my code;

```
Uri ringtone = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
    r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), ringtone);
    r.play();   

    /*
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "TAG");
    wakeLock.acquire();


    KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
    KeyguardLock keyguardLock =  keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock("TAG");
    keyguardLock.disableKeyguard(); 


    window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    */

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    WakeLock mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "MyService");
    mWakeLock.acquire();
    mWakeLock.release();

    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
```

What is wrong with this code?

Could you please help me?

I have tried all the answers you have offered,  but still there is no success

Comment: You don't actually get to "unlock" the device, though you can allow your activity to receive some limited interaction while the device remains effectively locked for other purposes.

Comment: could you please explain in more detail

Comment: It is simply not permitted for a 3rd party app to actually unlock the device in general.  There are many previous questions here on this topic.

Comment: but i witnessed that there is an app, unlock the device, it actually dismiss keyguard, appears the activity, after activity finishes its job, then call keyguard

Answer (score 0):

You need 3 flags, `FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD`, `FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` and `FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON`

```
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;
private Window window;
```

add this into your `onCreate()`

```
    window = this.getWindow();
    window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

or use `onResume()` method it works for me =)

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    window = this.getWindow();
    window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
}
```